# category sub categories products count(is anchor)

Tags: magento2, category-products

Any one please help me.
I need parent category count of products(is_anchor), but I get category count. It is not equal to actual products count.

```
<?php $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($catId);           
        $subcats = $subcategory->getChildrenCategories();
foreach ($subcats as $subcat) { 
                if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
                $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
                $_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl(); 
                    $subcat_url = $subcat->getUrl();
                   // echo $qty = $subcat->getQty(); exit;
                    $subcat_img = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/category/' . $subcat->getImage(); 
                    if($_imgUrl==''){
                    $_imgUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."catalog/category/notavailfull.gif";
            }
                    ?>
                    <div class="item-two">
                        <a href="<?php echo $subcat_url; ?>">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $_imgUrl; ?>"/>
                            <p><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
                            <span class="pro_quantity"><?php echo '('.$subcat->getProductCount().')' ;?></span></p>

                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <?php
                }
            }?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this I resloved the issue `<?php echo '('.$subcat->getProductCollection()->count().')';?>`

```
   <?php  foreach ($subcats as $subcat) { 
                        if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {
                        $_category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcat->getId());
                            $_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl(); 
                            $subcat_url = $subcat->getUrl();
                            $subcat_img = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/category/' . $subcat->getImage(); 
                            if($_imgUrl ==''){
                                $_imgUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."catalog/category/placeholder.png";
                            }
                            ?>
                            <div class="item">
                                <a href="<?php echo $subcat_url; ?>">
                                <span class="image_view_sec">
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $_imgUrl; ?>"/>
                                </span>
                                    <p><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?>
                                    <span class="pro_quantity"><?php echo '('.$subcat->getProductCollection()->count().')';?></span></p>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <?php
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
```